RDP: How do I achieve black screen on client computer while running an app on host computer to prevent screensharing
I am making a software on Windows, but I want to cause black screen upon screenshare without preventing RDP software. How do I achieve the black screen on the client when they try to access the host computer?

Please clarify what you mean by "...without preventing RDP software".  What research have you done regarding blanking a display in Windows programatically? What have you tried so far?
